# Laravel carbon parse Error: Failed to parse time string (1661731200) at position 8 (0): Unexpected character, but works locally

Tags: php-carbon, laravel-9, tinker

I have a timestring `1661731200` that works as expected when I parse it with Carbon via artisan tinker or in my code using

```
$time = "1661731200";
Carbon::parse($time);
```

[image: Code running on tinker]

But the same line of code fails with error  `Failed to parse time string (1661731200) at position 8 (0): Unexpected character` when encountered on the live server.

I'm looking to understand what might be causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `@` timestamp prefix:

```
$time = "@1661731200";
Carbon::parse($time);
```

Or it can be:

```
$time = "1661731200";
Carbon::createFromTimestamp($time);
```

Comment: this returns `7312-08-31 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)` as the time but that's quite wrong.

Comment: Are you on a 32bit system? Because both above work fine for me on PHP 8 and on https://try-carbon-package.herokuapp.com/